# Responsive Vertical Slider with jQuery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, slider, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make a vertical slider with jQuery that responds to change in screen size and is mobile friendly. I've looked at libraries such as slick (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and lightSlider (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/index.html). What I'm looking for is something like the first example show here (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html) except vertical. Although both libraries support vertical modes and responsive functionality, when I try to make a vertical slider, I can't make it responsive.

The settings of the light slider are assigned like so:

```
var settings = {
    item:5,
    loop: true,
    vertical: true,
    controls: true,
    mode: 'slide',
    pager: false,
    enableTouch: true,
    slideMargin:-10,
    pause: 1000,
    speed: 400,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 300,
            item: 3
        }
    ]
};
```

The attribute 'breakpoint' specifies the sizes at which to adjust the settings of the slider, however I've noticed it only applies to window width. Is there any way to check for window height instead, when the slider is in vertical mode?

Comment: you have `adaptiveHeight: true` which reacts to the content, so if you wanted to make your own breakpoints for height, you probably have to disable that option.

Comment: add a JSFiddle so we can test the code